# How to make textbox half readonly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a question about a textbox in asp.net. I have an text for example : P-70101002-00089-0, and I want that just this part : "70101002" to be readonly and the other part the users to have the ability to edit.
The template is always the same just the numbers change.
Is there any opportunity to make it with asp.net or any javascript?
Thank you

Comment: If I were you, I would simply stick 2 textboxes, remove their right/left border, to give the impression it is a single textbox, and allow the right textbox to be written but not the left textbox.

Comment: Just use labels for the prefix and suffix and have the input as what you want to get from user?

Comment: Use masking for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
var x  = $('#myId').val().length;
$('#myId').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {    
    if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
        && ((this.selectionStart < x)
        || ((this.selectionStart == x) && (event.which == 8)))) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Yt72H/287/)**

Comment: Right click, paste and this is not working. I would listen on the `input` event instead.

Comment: I cant use in asp for example value="70101002" as u used, because it changes for otherexamples.I am using this in asp.net.  <asp:TextBox ID="CadastralNumberTextBox" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="CadastralNumberTextBoxResource1"
                                            Text='<%# Bind("CadastralNumber") %>' Width="98%" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: @user2568960:- You can make changes in the CSS and HTML only like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kaf4j/9/

Answer (score 0):

**we can make it using hidden input that we'll use to get read-only text**

```js
function eidturl() {
  var readOnlyLength = $('#page_name_field_hidden').val().length;
  $('#page_name_field').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
    if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39)) &&
      ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength) ||
        ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="page_name_field" type="text" onclick="eidturl()" name="app_name" value="70101002" size="50" />
<input id="page_name_field_hidden" type="hidden" value="70101002" size="50" />
```

Comment: It may help. You can test using run code snippet click

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bootstrap with InputGroup

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">P-70101002-</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="00089-0" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
```